# Como selecionar o maior valor da seguinte consulta?

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT SUM(DISCIPLINA.VALOR) + MATRICULA.VALOR
    FROM ALUNO, MATRICULA, MATDISCIPLINA, DISCIPLINA, SEMESTRE
    WHERE ALUNO.CDALUNO = MATRICULA.CDALUNO
        AND MATRICULA.CDSEMESTRE = SEMESTRE.CDSEMESTRE
        AND MATRICULA.CDMATRICULA = MATDISCIPLINA.CDMATRICULA 
        AND MATDISCIPLINA.CDDISCIPLINA = DISCIPLINA.CDDISCIPLINA
        AND SEMESTRE.ANO = '2018.1'
    GROUP BY ALUNO.NOME
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar os valores do SELECT entre o ```max()``` ?

Mais ou menos assim: ```SELECT max(SUM(DISCIPLINA.VALOR) + MATRICULA.VALOR)``` ?

Comment: Ja tentei o mysql retorna esse erro: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Utilize: SUM(DISCIPLINA.VALOR) + SUM(MATRICULA.VALOR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar a consulta acima como `subquery`:

```
SELECT MAX(x.total)
  FROM (
  SELECT SUM(DISCIPLINA.VALOR) + MATRICULA.VALOR AS total
    FROM ALUNO, MATRICULA, MATDISCIPLINA, DISCIPLINA, SEMESTRE
   WHERE ALUNO.CDALUNO = MATRICULA.CDALUNO
     AND MATRICULA.CDSEMESTRE = SEMESTRE.CDSEMESTRE
     AND MATRICULA.CDMATRICULA = MATDISCIPLINA.CDMATRICULA 
     AND MATDISCIPLINA.CDDISCIPLINA = DISCIPLINA.CDDISCIPLINA
     AND SEMESTRE.ANO = '2018.1'
   GROUP BY ALUNO.NOME
) x
```

Comment: Obrigado colega.

Comment: @HiagoPais se a resposta lhe atendeu não esqueça de aceitá-la